# jQuery how to get body contents out of html reponse

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a bit of a problem.

I have an ajax request that is sent out to do a database update. A response is then returned that looks like:

```
...
...
</head>
<body class="contentpane">
{"id":"27","votes":14,"sum":45,"avg":"3.2"}
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the contents of body class "contentpane" and then convert this to a JSON object?

My request function looks like this:

```
  jQuery.post("index.php?option=com_ttvideo&task=savevote&tmpl=component", {rate: value, id: <?php echo $this->video->id; ?> }, function(html)
  {
    // get contents of "contentpane" from response html
    // convert to JSON object e.g.
    // var rating = jQuery.parseJSON(content_of_body);    
    // is the above JSON parse correct?    

    // Select stars to match "Average" value
    ui.select(Math.round(rating.avg));

    // Update other text controls...
    jQuery("#avg").text(rating.avg);
    jQuery("#votes").text(rating.votes);

    // Show Stars
    jQuery("#loader").hide();
    jQuery("#rat").show();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$.parseJSON($('body', html).text())
```

I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that the JSON will be HTML escaped.  If it isn't, you will sometimes be able to call `.html()` instead of `.text()`, but will more likely need to write your own parser.

You should replace your webservice with a real JSON response.

Comment: This is a component I am developing in Joomla and to keep the php functions within the Joomla framework it requires to run the response through the component MVC framework - draw back of this is that it returns all that html as well, tut tut :(

Comment: I'm trying to work through this 1 step at a time, 1. getting the value out of the body tag using var rating = jQuery("body", html).text(); but this returns blank, replacing with .html() returns null.

Comment: @Martin: I can't imagine that there is no way around that.  However, I don't know Joomla.  Ask a separate question here.

Comment: Try `$(html).find('body').text()`.

Comment: Thanks but I found this article about JSON responses for MVC in Joomla - http://docs.joomla.org/Handling_the_server_side_of_Ajax_requests

Comment: Ok, I was doing everything right - when you make the request to your component then you need to add "&format=raw" to the end url. Duh! Thanks for your help SLaks, you pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

Pretty easy. Wrap inner of BODY by DIV will do:

```
$.get(url, {}, function(data){
  var data = data.replace('<body', '<body><div id="body"').replace('</body>','</div></body>');
  var body = $(data).filter('#body');
  (... do what you want with body ...)
});
```